# Functors in Isbell duality exchange $f^*a$ and $f_*a$

Tags: ct.category-theory

As you maybe remember, Isbell duality is an adjunction 
$$\mathcal O : [A°,Set] \leftrightarrows [A,Set]° : {\cal S}pec$$ 
as defined [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Isbell+duality); since every functor $f : A\to B$ defines both

1. a functor $f^* : B\to [A°,Set]$ by $$(a,b)\mapsto B(fa,b)$$ and
2. a functor $f_* : B\to [A,Set]°$ by $$(a,b)\mapsto B(b,fa)$$

then it is reasonable to ask

> is it true that $\mathcal O \circ f^*\cong f_*$ and ${\cal S}pec \circ f_* \cong f^*$?

In other words the presheaf $B(f\_\,,b)$ is exchanged with $B(b, f\_\,)$ by $\mathcal O$, and similarly $f_*b$ becomes $f^*b$ when it is post-composed with the ${\cal S}pec$ functor. Both $\cal O$ and ${\cal S}pec$ admit very explicit descriptions as
$$
\begin{gather*}
{\cal O}(P)(A) = Nat(P, \hom(\_\,,A))\\
{\cal S}pec(Q)(A) = Nat(Q, \hom(A,\_\,)),
\end{gather*}
$$
and while it seems to me that $\cal O$ has this property, I see no way to prove that
$$
Nat(B(b,f\_\,), \hom(a,\_\,)) \cong B(fa,b).
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's give names to these two separate conditions:
\begin{align}
Nat(B(b,f-),hom(a,-)) &\cong B(fa,b) \tag{1} \\
Nat(B(f-,b),hom(-,a)) &\cong B(b,fa) \tag{2} 
\end{align}
Neither of these must be true in general, though they hold under some natural conditions. I will treat (2) first, since (1) is completely dual.

As a counterexample, take $A = 1$ the terminal category, then $f$ corresponds to an object of $B$, and (2) reduces to a natural isomorphism
$$
Set(B(f,b),1) \cong 1 \cong B(b,f)
$$
which is false unless $f$ is a terminal object in $B$.

A sufficient condition for (2) is that $f : A \to B$ is both fully faithful and [dense](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dense+functor), meaning that there are natural isomorphisms
\begin{align}
A(a,a') &\cong B(fa,fa') \tag{$f$ fully faithful}\\
B(b,b') &\cong Nat(B(f-,b),B(f-,b')) \tag{$f$ dense}
\end{align}
We then derive (2) in two steps:
$$
Nat(B(f-,b),hom(-,a)) \cong Nat(B(f-,b),B(f-,fa)) \cong B(b,fa)
$$
(As an aside, it is perhaps worth mentioning that fully faithful and dense functors play a role in the theory of [monads with arities](https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.3064).)

Essentially the same counterexample works with (1) (now taking $f : 1 \to B$ to be any non-initial object of $B$), and for a sufficient condition we can replace density with the [codensity](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/codense+functor)-like assumption that the functor $f_* : B \to [A,Set]^\circ$ is fully faithful, i.e., that there is an isomorphism $B(b,b') \cong Nat(B(b',f-),B(b,f-))$.

**Update (14 June)**: Restoring original answer (with expanded commentary) after realizing the flaw in the OP's counterargument. The isomorphisms ${\mathcal O} \circ f^* \cong f_*$ and $Spec \circ f_* \cong f^*$ cannot follow by preservation of (left/right) Kan extensions along (left/right) adjoints, since $f^*$ is a *left* Kan extension while $f_*$ is a *right* Kan extension.

Comment: And yet it seems to me that ${\cal O}$ must send $Lan_fy=f^*$ to $Lan_fy^\sharp=f_*$ since it is a left adjoint:
$$
{\cal O} \circ B(f,1) = {\cal O}\circ Lan_f y_A \cong Lan_f ({\cal O} \circ y_A) \cong Lan_f y_A^\sharp = B(1,f)
$$ where $y^\sharp : A \to [A,Set]°$...

Comment: I must be missing something. When $A = 1$, the Isbell adjunction reduces to the contravariant adjunction on Set induced by exponentiation into the singleton set. I don't see how composing with $1^{(-)}$ has a hope of transporting $f^*$ to $f_*$, or vice versa, unless $f : 1 \to B$ is an initial/terminal object.

Comment: @FoscoLoregian Okay, I've thought about this again (sleep is good!), and I'm pretty sure my original answer and counterexample were correct. The reason why your argument above doesn't work is simply that $f_*$ is not the *left* Kan extension of $y^\sharp$ along $F$, it is the *right* Kan extension.

Comment: Isbell adjunction is contravariant, I thought this took care of the fact you point out. But maybe I've been tricked into believing this by an incorrect number of dualizations? I agree with your counterexample, but I need to understand more what's going on. So: I'm surely accepting the answer, but can you please elaborate on $B(1,f)$ being a *right* and non-left extension? (perhaps you prefer to discuss the topic in chat?)

Comment: I was confused as well, but since $[A,Set]^\circ = [A^\circ,Set^\circ]$, the point is that a natural transformation $G \Rightarrow H : B \to [A,Set]^\circ$ corresponds to a family of maps $G(b)(a) \to H(b)(a)$ in $Set^\circ$, hence a family of functions $H(b)(a) \to G(b)(a)$. Then $B(1,f)$ is a right Kan extension rather than a left Kan extension, with the counit $\epsilon : B(1,f) \circ f \Rightarrow y^\sharp$ corresponding to the family of functions $A(a',a) \to B(fa',fa)$.

Comment: I am sorry to continue pushing this apparently boring point, but if I try to write Kan formula for $Lan_f(y^\sharp)(b)(a')$ it comes to me that
$$
\left(\int^a y^\sharp(a)\times B°(fa,b)\right)(a')\cong \int^a \hom(a,a')\times B(b,fa)=B(b,fa')
$$
whereas the dual formula for $Ran_f(y^\sharp)(b)(a')$ yields
$$
\left(\int_a y^\sharp(a)^{B°(b,fa)}\right)(a')\cong Nat(B(f-,b), A(-,a')) = {\cal O}(f^*(b))(a')
$$
This is compatible with [Todd Trimble's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/260384/7952).

Comment: for the first formula, since the Kan extension is along $f : A \to B$, why do you have $\int^a y^\sharp(a) \times B^\circ(fa,b)$ rather than $\int^a y^\sharp(a) \times B(fa,b)$?

Comment: The second integral depends on $a$ contravariantly in both variables, this doesn't allow you to compute the coend.

Comment: I think that the computation you are doing actually corresponds to the left Kan extension of $y^{\sharp\circ} : A^\circ \to [A,Set]$ along $f^\circ : A^\circ \to B^\circ$. This gives you $B(1,f)^\circ : B^\circ \to [A,Set]$ rather than $B(1,f)$, and taking opposites $B(1,f)^{\circ\circ} = B(1,f)$ turns the left Kan extension into a right Kan extension.

Comment: (Remember that taking opposite categories defines an operation on Cat [which reverses the direction of the 2-cells](https://mathoverflow.net/a/176330/1015).)

Comment: Now I see what was going wrong and your counterexample doesn't collide any more with my understanding of Isbell adjunction :-) ah, duality: the most underrated phenomenon in category theory.

Comment: the question below is also adressed to you. Thanks for your help and patience!

Answer (score 1):

I think a formally similar result is true provided we redefine $f^*$ and $f_*$.

Covariant and contravariant Yoneda embeddings commute with Isbell functors in the sense that

$Spec \circ Z \cong Y$

$\mathcal{O} \circ Y \cong Z$

where $A \xrightarrow{Y(A)} [A^{op}, set]$ and $A \xrightarrow{Z(A)}[set, A]^{op}$.

The isomorphisms are just evaluations $\chi^{Y}$ and $\chi^{Z}$ (Street-Walters notation) which are iso since $Y$ and $Z$ are full and faithfull.

For $A \xrightarrow[]{f} B$ it follows directly that

$Spec \circ f^* \cong f_*$

$\mathcal{O} \circ f_* \cong f^*$

provided $f^* := Z(B) \circ f $   and $f_* := Y(B) \circ f $.

This means that $B(f(a), \_ )$ and $B(\_, f(a))$ are converted to each other by composition with Isbell functors.

Comment: Yes, that is precisely what's written in the "Roma lecture notes"! In fact one has simply to distinguish (what you call) $B\langle f,1\rangle$ from (what you call) $B(f,1)$. These functors correspond each other under op-ing and un-currying.

Comment: This is solved and I'm happy with it, but do you have any clue about how to prove that $B\langle f,1\rangle$ and $B(f,1)$ correspond each other under the adjunction $P^\sharp\dashv P$ recalled [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/302678/ambidextrous-yoneda-structures-admissibles-and-adjunctions)? I expect it to be true.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that question? Not sure if this gets at what you are asking, but working in terms of distributors, $B(f,1) : B \to A$ can be defined as the left Kan extension of the identity $A \to A$ along $B\langle f,1\rangle : A \to B$, so automatically $B\langle f,1\rangle \dashv B(f,1)$.

Comment: The question means the following: given $f :A\to B$, does the functor $B(f-_2, -_1) : B\to PA$ correspond to $B(f-_1,-_2) : A\to P^\sharp B$ under the adjunction isomorphism $[B, PA]\cong [A, P^\sharp B]$. I have a proof for this, with a certain amount of pain to write down unit and counit for $P^\sharp\dashv P$.