# What if adjoints are just too big to give unit and counit?

Tags: ct.category-theory

$\def\CAT{\mathbf{Cat}}\def\Set{Set}\def\bsP{P}$In the category $\CAT$ of possibly large categories, one can build a pseudo-adjunction $P^\sharp \dashv P$ where

- $P$ is the functor $A\mapsto [A°,Set]$;
- $P^\sharp$ is the functor $A\mapsto [A,Set]°$; both these functors are parallel $\CAT^{coop}\to \CAT$
- the isomorphism 
  $$
  \CAT(B, PA)\cong \CAT(A, P^\sharp B)^\text{op}
  $$ is given by cartesian transposition:
  $$
  \CAT(A, [B^\text{op},\Set]) \cong \CAT(B^\text{op}, [A,\Set])\cong\CAT(B, [A,\Set]^\text{op})^\text{op}$$

For the mere sake to play a game, one could try to write down the adjunction data induced by this isomorphism: in particular,

1. A "unit" is determined as the image of the identity $1_{\bsP^\sharp B}$ along the isomorphism $\CAT^\text{coop}(\bsP^\sharp B,\bsP^\sharp B)\cong \CAT(B,\bsP\bsP^\sharp B)$ and results as the map
   $$\eta_B : B \to [[B,\Set],\Set] : b \mapsto (\Delta\mapsto\Delta(b))$$
2. a "counit" is determined as the image of the identity $1_{\bsP A}$ along the isomorphism $\CAT(\bsP A,\bsP A)\cong \CAT(\bsP^\sharp\bsP A,A)^\text{op} = \CAT^\text{coop}(A,\bsP^\sharp\bsP A)$ and (similarly) results as the map
   $$\epsilon_A^\text{op} : A \to [[A^\text{op},Set],\Set]^\text{op} : a \mapsto (\Gamma\mapsto \Gamma(a))$$
3. A similar disdain for size issues shows that these maps satisfy suitable zig-zag identities. So it seems that the functors are also adjoints using co/unit 2-cells.

Complying to the superstition that mathematical language carries meaning, however, this makes no sense: the "categories" $K=[[A^\text{op},Set],Set]^\text{op}$ are not legitimate objects, and even more so the "category" $\bsP K$ needed to prove the triangle identities for $\bsP^\sharp\dashv \bsP$ isn't legitimate.

> Is there a way to solve this issue?

Since my ultimate goal is to formalize this solution enough to apply it to a generic 2-category with an [ambidextrous Yoneda structure](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/302678/ambidextrous-yoneda-structures-admissibles-and-adjunctions), the more your answer is formal, the happier I will be accepting it.

Of course, every suggestion is more than welcome.

Comment: This will be dependent on how precisely you’re dealing with size issues, but I can’t see any reading that quite makes everything you say hold.  If you use a Grothendieck universe for your small/large distinction, then there is no problem at all — you can form $P^{\sharp}PA$ and so on quite happily, so the unit and counit are fine.  On the other hand, if you take small/large to mean set/proper class (as in NBG or similar), then the problem occurs sooner than units/counits, already at the point of considering that $P$ as a functor on $\mathrm{Cat}$: $PA$ is not defined for general large $A$.

Comment: What about working in CAT, forgetting about the usual *locally small* assumption?

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine I agree that the problem (kind of) disappears if one adopts TG as foundation. But as I said my ultimate goal is to say something about a similar adjunction $P^\sharp = P(-^\text{op})^\text{op} \dashv P$ in a Yoneda structure, where I have nothing but an ideal of "admissibles". And yes, ultimately the presheaf construction is not an endofunctor: the problem is adressed [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.03678) as one main motivation to produce the definition of "relative pseudomonad".

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti one could even guess that in a representable structure, where $P  = [-^\text{op},\Omega]$, the correspondence is defined everywhere by the cartesian closed structure of $\cal K$, but unfortunately one is bound to specify admissibles by the fact that the Yoneda arrow $A\to PA$ isn't defined for all objects, only for admissibles.

Comment: Relative pseudomonads are a legitimate way to deal with sizes. The one I am suggesting goes in a different direction. As soon as $[^{\text{op}}, \Omega]$ is defined for all objects, there is no need for the specification of an ideal.

It looks to me that [C, Set] is a legitimate *huge* category (not locally small) for any category $C$.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is.  As Peter says, if you use a Grothendieck universe then it all seems to be fine.  In particular, $P$ is a perfectly good endofunctor of the 2-category of locally-large categories.  And you need a Grothendieck universe to construct a Yoneda structure anyway, don't you?  The only thing that fails to exist in general is the Yoneda arrow, but that doesn't play any role in the adjunction discussed in your question.